# Ionic 4 Android 8+ How can I get device's IMEI

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, imei

I'm trying to get the device IMEI

I'm using Typescript and Angular. The Ionic UID plugin was working normally but on Android 8+ it's not working.

Can anyone provide me with some information

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "plugin was working normally" ? Did you mean that you were able to read a device IMEI code previously but with Android 8+ you cant do that ? 

I do not think its possible to read a device's IMEI code without user's consent. Its strictly sensitive information.

Comment: On Android 7 and the lower versions, I was able to read the device IMEI yes. I just needed the user to allow access to READ_PHONE_STATE using the Ionic plugin UID. 
On Android 8+ even when the user allow access to this permission - the IMEI is returned as null